# ExecJS RuntimeError on Session Logout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, logout

I am getting a ExecJS::RuntimeError when I try to view localhost:3000. It displays this:

`(in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/turbolinks-1.1.1/lib/assets/javascripts/turbolinks.js.coffee)`

and highlights this as the main problem.

`<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>`

Without the line included the application works (user signup, user login) but the logout function doesn't work and I believe i need the above line included to reference the files in `/app/assets/javascripts`

Without the javascripts link the application works but any attempt to signout produces this error:

No route matches [GET] "/signout"

even though I have the following in my `/config/routes.rb` file:

`match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy',  via: 'delete'`

**/app/assets/javasacripts/application.js**

```
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: which version of ruby and rails you are using

Comment: rails 4.0.2 and ruby 1.9.3. After I updated to 4.0.2 when I run `rails new application` and run the server straight away; I get the same problem with the javascript tag in the application layout.

Comment: from which version of rails you have updated your application to 4.0.2. also did the bundle run successfully?

Comment: updated from rails 4.0.0. It appeared to run successfully in the sense that it didn't throw up any errors or crash when installing.

Comment: remove this part ", "data-turbolinks-track" => true", run bundle and try.can u post your application.js here

Comment: I still get the same error. Would it make a difference if I said I tried creating a new skeleton app and when I ran the server I could view the localhost root page with the rails welcome message?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45958/discussion-between-ghostrider-and-aluxzi)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a way to fix it by removing the line `//= require_tree .` After looking into the error a little more I found another (old) SO topic that touched on the same subject but it didn't give a full reason this solution worked; only briefly mentioned that, while allowing the application to work, this was ignoring the problem rather than fixing it.